# Videos are marked as private

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We have a CMS system and users can upload their videos directly to their YouTube channel via YouTube API.
The consent screen of the YouTube API app has been reviewed and released by YouTube, but the uploaded videos are still automatically blocked.

Is there a way to find out why?

Comment: I think you better [ask this from Google](http://issuetracker.google.com/).

Comment: If your application that uses the youtube api has not yet been verified all videos will be marked as private until the application has completed the review process.   Once the process has been completed you should be able to update them to public.   This will not be done automatically.

Comment: My application (the consent screen) has been verified. Is there another verfication I need to request?